# size differenring after scp from one machine to another

Tags: scp

I have a file size of 7.5Gb which I transferred from one solaris machine to another solaris machine through scp. after scp the file is showing 13Gb in destination server.I would like to know what's reason for this?

Comment: What type of file is it? What type are the source and target file systems?

Comment: how you check the size, and show the comman you use.

Answer (score 1):

One way this can happen is files with "holes": [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). Suppose a program does something like:

```
fd = open("somefile", O_RDWR);
seek(fd, 1024, SEEK_SET);
write(fd, "blah blah", 9);
```

The `seek()` system call skips over what would be the first disk block of the file (I think, it's been a while since I've used Solaris), and writes 9 bytes in the second block. Most/all Unix and Linux filesystems won't actually allocate the first, never-written, disk block. If you copy the file, or archive it or something, it grows, as any `read()` made on the first 1024 bytes of the file return all zero bytes.

That said, it's really rare to encounter such a situation. I'd look harder for some bug, like double-copying or something.

You can check whether the source file is sparse by comparing its size and its disk usage:

```
ls -l the_file
du -k the_file
```

If the second figure (disk usage) is smaller than the first (actual file size), the file is sparse.

If the file is sparse, you can use `rsync -a --sparse` to transfer it instead of `scp`. Rsync can copy sparse files to sparse files if you tell it to.